# Pandas: How do I normalize COVID-19 dataframe with different countries having different day of outbreak

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In order to meaningfully compare across territories, I would like to normalize the COVID-19 confirmed cases by the starting date of the outbreak in different countries. For any territory, the day that territory reaches or exceeds 10 confirmed cases is considered as 'day 0 of the outbreak.

Example dataframe:

```
[in]
import pandas as pd
confirmed_cases = {'Date':['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', '1/25/20', '1/26/20'], 'Australia':[0, 0, 0, 30, 50], 'Albania':[0, 20, 25, 30, 50], 'Algeria':[25, 40, 50, 50, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(confirmed_cases)
df

[out]
    Date    Australia   Albania     Algeria
0   1/22/20        0         0          25
1   1/23/20        0        20          40
2   1/24/20        0        25          50
3   1/25/20       30        30          50
4   1/26/20       50        50          70
```

Desired Results:

```
    Day Since Outbreak     Australia    Albania     Algeria
0           0                    30         20          25
1           1                    50         25          40
2           2                   NaN         30          50
3           3                   NaN         50          50
4           4                   NaN        NaN          70
```

Are there any ways to perform this task with simple lines of Python/Panda code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find the index value of the first value exceeding threshold (10) for each country and shift each column up by that many

```
df2 = df[['Australia', 'Albania', 'Algeria']].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-(x > 10).idxmax()))
# df2
   Australia  Albania  Algeria
0       30.0     20.0       25
1       50.0     25.0       40
2        NaN     30.0       50
3        NaN     50.0       50
4        NaN      NaN       70
```

reset the index to get the day-since column

```
df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Day Since Outbreak'})

   Day Since Outbreak  Australia  Albania  Algeria
0                   0       30.0     20.0       25
1                   1       50.0     25.0       40
2                   2        NaN     30.0       50
3                   3        NaN     50.0       50
4                   4        NaN      NaN       70
```

Comment: Nice use of idxmax. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston, thanks, I was literally playing with covid data over the weekend, and did this already very recently

Answer (score 1):

Determine how many times you need to `shift` each column based on the first run of values < 10. Then shift them. The `cummin` ensures that if there's an intermittent value < 10 it doesn't get counted in the `shift`

```
df = df.drop(columns='Date')  # Wont need
s = df.lt(10).cummin().sum()

for col, shift in s.iteritems():
    df[col] = df[col].shift(-shift)

df['Days Since'] = range(len(df)) # Duplicative with index...
```

---

```
   Australia  Albania  Algeria  Days Since
0       30.0     20.0       25           0
1       50.0     25.0       40           1
2        NaN     30.0       50           2
3        NaN     50.0       50           3
4        NaN      NaN       70           4
```